# Do not autosave belongs-to association

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model Subscription with a belongs-to association to Participant.

The subscription form uses fields_for to build the associated participant fields.

Also in the form is a radio button called called 'other_person'.

What I want is to NOT save the associated participant table (so also not validate) when the other_person field is set to false.

Comment: Please post some code example with what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume `other_person` is a field of the `Subscription` model on the following example:

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :remove_empty_participant
  belongs_to :participant

  private

  def remove_empty_participant
    self.participant = nil unless self.other_person
  end
end
```

If it's not a field of your `Subscription` model, you will have to remove the attributes in the controller's action:

```
class SubscriptionsController < ActionController

  def create
    params[:subscription].delete(:participant) unless params[:other_person]
    # Save the subscription with your current params...
  end

end
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, other_person is indeed a field of the Subscription model. I tried this solution as well. It works partially, in that it doesn't save the associated participant_id in the Subscription model. However, it DOES save the participant in the Participant table. (probably because it inserts the participant first and THEN inserts the subscription)

Comment: Yes, most likely. In order to get the participant_id, the Participant must be saved first. Did you try the alternative approach of cleaning your `params` before they get into your `Subscription` model?

Comment: Yes, that works! (Although I use :participant_attributes) :) THANK YOU